# How to Sum Distinct Values of duplicate fields

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

Iam new here and hope i can find some help here.

I have following Problem: [Fiddle SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76470/4/0)

```
CREATE TABLE TestData
    (
      [Acct] INT ,
      [Desc] VARCHAR(100) ,
      [OU01] VARCHAR(100) ,
      [OU02] VARCHAR(100) ,
      DEPTHS INT
    );

CREATE TABLE TestDepends
    (
      [Acct] INT ,
      [SecondKey] NUMERIC(9, 0) ,
      [Name] VARCHAR(100) ,
      [COST] NUMERIC(9, 0) ,
      [used] TINYINT ,
      [OU01] VARCHAR(100) ,
      [OU02] VARCHAR(100)
    );



INSERT  INTO TestData
VALUES  ( 1, 'Feld 1', 'OU01', '', 1 );
INSERT  INTO TestData
VALUES  ( 1, 'Feld 1', 'OU01', 'OU02', 2 );
INSERT  INTO TestData
VALUES  ( 1, 'Feld 1', 'OU01', 'OU03', 2 );
INSERT  INTO TestData
VALUES  ( 1, 'Feld 1', 'OU02', '', 1 );


INSERT  INTO TestDepends
VALUES  ( 1, 21, 'Name 1', 120, 0, 'OU01', 'OU02' );
INSERT  INTO TestDepends
VALUES  ( 1, 22, 'Name 2', 50, 0, 'OU01', '' );
INSERT  INTO TestDepends
VALUES  ( 1, 21, 'Name 1', 120, 1, 'OU01', 'OU02' );
INSERT  INTO TestDepends
VALUES  ( 1, 23, 'Name 3', 111, 0, 'OU01', 'OU03' );
INSERT  INTO TestDepends
VALUES  ( 1, 24, 'Name 4', 99, 0, 'OU02', '' );
INSERT  INTO TestDepends
VALUES  ( 1, 25, 'Name 5', 120, 0, 'OU01', 'OU02' );

SELECT  TD.Acct ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT TDS.SecondKey) AS Found ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TDS.Used = 1 THEN TDS.SecondKey
                       END) AS Used ,
        TD.OU01 ,
        TD.OU02
FROM    TestData TD
        INNER JOIN TestDepends TDS ON TDS.Acct = TD.Acct
                                      AND ( TD.OU01 = ''
                                            OR ISNULL(TD.OU01, '') = ISNULL(TDS.OU01, '')
                                          )
                                      AND ( TD.OU02 = ''
                                            OR ISNULL(TD.OU02, '') = ISNULL(TDS.OU02, '')
                                          )
WHERE   TD.depths = 2
GROUP BY TD.Acct ,
        TD.OU01 ,
        TD.OU02
```

As you can see in the first Select i count the distinct Data (SecondKey) and this works perfectly.

Now i want to sum up all costs of all distinct Data

```
  SELECT  TD.Acct ,
            SUM(TDS.Cost) AS Cost ,
            SUM(TDS.Cost) AS Cost ,
            TD.OU01 ,
            TD.OU02
    FROM    TestData TD
            INNER JOIN TestDepends TDS ON TDS.Acct = TD.Acct
                                          AND ( TD.OU01 = ''
                                                OR ISNULL(TD.OU01, '') = ISNULL(TDS.OU01, '')
                                              )
                                          AND ( TD.OU02 = ''
                                                OR ISNULL(TD.OU02, '') = ISNULL(TDS.OU02, '')
                                              )
    WHERE   TD.depths = 2
    GROUP BY TD.Acct ,
            TD.OU01 ,
            TD.OU02
```

As you can see it sums up the "duplicate" (not the whole row is a duplicate, but the SecondKeys) rows too. Is it possible to sum up all Costs of only distinct SecondKeys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I've got it right you need to JOIN not with `TestDepends` but with a query with `GROUP BY` to avoid duplicates:

```
....
FROM    TestData TD
        INNER JOIN 
           ( 
            SELECT Acct,
                   SecondKey,   
                   Name,
                   cost,
                   MAX(used) as used,
                   OU01,
                   OU02
             FROM
             TestDepends 
             GROUP BY Acct,SecondKey,Name,cost, OU01, OU02
           )  
         TDS ON ....
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76470/12)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your help. this works :) Now i will try to eliminate the horrible OU Structure. At the moment in the current SQL Procedure for every OU the sql is copied... (8 OU at the moment) i believe it must be possible to make it without copy paste :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:
I've eliminated the duplicates using the `Distinct` keyword and not choosing the `USED` column in the derived table `t1`

```
  SELECT  TD.Acct ,
            SUM(t1.Cost) AS Cost ,           
            TD.OU01 ,
            TD.OU02
    FROM    TestData TD
            INNER JOIN
              (select distinct Acct, Secondkey, Name, Cost, ou01, ou02 
               from TestDepends) t1 ON t1.Acct = TD.Acct
                                          AND ( TD.OU01 = ''
                                                OR ISNULL(TD.OU01, '') = ISNULL(t1.OU01, '')
                                              )
                                          AND ( TD.OU02 = ''
                                                OR ISNULL(TD.OU02, '') = ISNULL(t1.OU02, '')
                                              )
    WHERE   TD.depths = 2
    GROUP BY TD.Acct ,
            TD.OU01 ,
            TD.OU02
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76470/23

Comment: thanks for your help, sadly i need the used column. in my final result i need to use case When to decide if i count the SecondKey or if i take a sum over the distinct values.